# Efficient Stereo matching Algoirithm in Windows

Tags: c++, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

I want to compute the disparity map in Windows platform. I have used several codes on the internet, but I can't compute precision disparity map. I have used Opencv SGBM algorithm, but the disparity map was very noisy. could any one introduce an efficient code?
Thanks in advance for you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, stereo vision is always a decision between speed and accuracy. You can't have both. SGM or SGBM are already doing a pretty good compromise here. If you want very high precision you can move towards true global algorithms such as belief propagation, but expect several minutes computation time for processing a single camera frame.

If you want fast processing, you can use block matching. But here you will get poor performance on low texture surfaces and effects like foreground fattening.

The only way to speed things up is to switch to a hardware that is capable of massively parallel processing. There exist some great FPGA-based solutions for stereo vision like this one:
https://nerian.com/products/sp1-stereo-vision/

Also using a (high-end) graphics card would be an option. There exist several research papers with proposed implementations and there might be some code available somewhere.